# How to optimize this airflow operator code to use minimal RAM on the celery worker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, list-comprehension, airflow

I'm using Airflow (Astronomer.io deployment), and this DAG code is on a Celery deployment.

This DAG gets data from the database (SQL Server) and then performs the following operations on the list of records. Below is a snippet that, since this is Airflow, uses SQLAlchemy to get the data, and then I convert it to a list.

```
# Perform query and convert returned tuple to list
logging.info(f"QUERY: {query}")
results = list(hook.get_records(query))
logging.info("Successfully performed MSSQL query:")
# logging.info(f"{results}")

results = [dict([k.lower(), str(v)] if v is not None else [k, v]
                for k, v in i.items()) for i in results]
results = '\n'.join([json.dumps(i) for i in results])
results = results.encode('utf-8')

logging.info("Uploading!")
fout.write(results)
```

This code ends up having the celery worker cycle until it times out right after the step having the log message "Successfully performed MSSQL query".

It seems the list comprehension does not perform well on 2 million + rows.

I'm fairly new to list comprehensions, so I'm looking for a way to optimize this so as not to have to use so many resources (RAM) in my celery workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `get_records` reads the entire result set into memory.

You want to limit the number of rows in memory at any given time.

What you want is a generator.  Something like this:

```
class MyOp(BaseOperator):
    BATCH_SIZE = 10000

    def get_rows(self):
        with self.hook.get_conn() as cnx:
            cur = cnx.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            while True:
                curr_batch = cur.fetchmany(self.BATCH_SIZE)
                if not curr_batch:
                    break
                yield from curr_batch
    
    def execute(self, context=None):
        rows = self.get_rows()
        self.do_something_with_rows(rows)
```

Here you retrieve 10k rows at a time, and yield them as you go.

Alternatively, you could use another method on that hook, `get_pandas_df`, and pass it the parameter `chunksize` and it will yield lists of size `chunksize`, which you can process as you go in a similar way.

The method `do_something_with_rows` I have left for you to implement, but typically what you do is write to an ephemeral local temp file and then upload to some service. See the `tempfile` library and its usages in airflow for examples.